# Mac osx launchd daemon and sockets

Tags: macos, sockets, daemon, launchd

I have an osx daemon that listen on port 8080.

My plist file: com.mycompany.daemon.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.mycompany.daemon</string>
    <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Applications/MyApp/MyDaemon</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
    <key>MyListener</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>8080</string>
            <key>SockType</key>
            <string>stream</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I'm hitting the port 8080 via curl or the browser, my daemon starts as expected but I need to get the opened socket from launchd to get the sent message and send a response. Following [the code sample from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SampleD/Introduction/Intro.html), I'm using launch.h to get that socket.

```
if ((checkin_request = launch_data_new_string(LAUNCH_KEY_CHECKIN)) == NULL) {
    retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
    goto done;
}

if ((checkin_response = launch_msg(checkin_request)) == NULL) {
    asl_log(asl, log_msg, ASL_LEVEL_ERR, "launch_msg(\"" LAUNCH_KEY_CHECKIN "\") IPC failure: %m");
    retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
    goto done;
}
```

my issue comes here, when I'm trying to CheckIn via launch_msg() , I get the "Operation not permitted" error. I tried to launch my daemon as root with no success. Is it the good way to do ? is there an other way to get the opened socket ? I'm using osx 10.9.2. Thanks.